# Android: Viewpager with multiple fragments of the same class with fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

There are already some open threads about this subject but mine is a little different and I can't seem to find out how to do it. This is my problem:

I'm creating a listview (recyclerview) inside a fragment which I put inside my Viewpager. This listview represent a timeline/agenda of the current day. Whenever the user swipe left or right, the exact same listview fragment needs to pop up with different data (data from the day before or after). Whenever you click on one of the items in the listview, the fragment is replaced by a detailed fragment.

This doesn't sounds so hard but here comes the tricky part:

All the examples I see on the internet show different Fragment classes inside the Viewpager which makes it possible to do a transaction from the listfragment to the detailed fragment, and all the examples that use multiple fragments of the same class don't do a transaction to a detailed fragment.

Whenever I'm trying to do the transaction to the detailed fragment, it looks like it can't find the proper fragment container (since there are 3 of the same now). I'm pretty sure of it since the new fragment does appear but the old fragment stays visibile underneath (when I don't use the viewpager it works fine).

If anyone could provide me with a simple example of a viewpager with multiple fragments of the same class that have a transaction to a detailed fragment you would save my day.

Regards